# How remove whitespaces in the beginning of lines?

Tags: whitespace, text

Emacs 26.1

I has the next text:

[image]

I need to remove all whitespaces in the beginning of the lines.
Every line has different count of whitespaces.
The result must be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Another way is just to mark the region and call delete-whitespace-rectangle!

Comment: It's cool!!! Thanks. I don't know about this.

Comment: best solution, ty.

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 8):

IMHO the standard way is:

1. Go to the top of your buffer.
2. Type <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> for [`query-replace-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html).
3. Input `^\s-+` as regular expression and <kbd>RET</kbd>. (See explanation below.)
4. Leave the replacement string empty, i.e., press <kbd>RET</kbd> again.
5. You are prompted by `query-replace-regexp` in the minibuffer.
   Press <kbd>!</kbd> to perform all replacements at once.

Explanation of the regular expression:

1. [The caret `^` stands for the beginning of line.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special)
2. [The `\s-` stands for any character designated as space by the current modes syntax table.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)
3. [The `+` stands for one or more contiguous matches.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex inside emacs (C-M-s). Check here [emacs regex](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression). By using regex you can write a rule that matches all the blanks that are at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do: use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regex`, then use <kbd>SPC</kbd> as input to this command (i.e. align on space), then use rectangle-editing commands: <kbd>C-x r k</kbd> for example to delete rectangle before the lines.

This is not terribly efficient, but it's how I do it because I use both commands very often and they are, sort of, automatic for me (muscle memory, or w/e you call it).